# How to access variables from another method

Tags: java, scope

I have a class named "Game" in Java, and the aim/goal is to reach a certain room, the "throne" room. When the throne room is reached the game ends.

```
public class Game {

    // fields

    private Room currentRoom;
    private boolean finished;
    private Room throne;

    /**
     * Create the game and initialise its internal map.
     */
    public Game() 
    {
        finished = false;
        createRooms();
    }

    /**
     * Create all the rooms and link their exits together.
     */
    private void createRooms()
    {
        Room gate, graveyard, church, crypt, entrance, hall, kitchen, buttery, greathall, staircase,
        dungeon, topstaircase, throne, solar, wardrobe, privy;

        // create the rooms
        gate = new Room("outside the old gate of the castle");
        graveyard = new Room("on a wind-swept gaveyard");
        church = new Room("in a small ancient church");
        throne = new Room("in the throne room with golden walls");
        // other rooms ...

        // initialize room exits

        gate.setExit("north", graveyard);
        throne.setExit("south", topstaircase);
        // other exits ...
    }
}
```

To go in one direction/room :

```
public String goRoom(String direction) 
{
    assert direction != null : "Game.goRoom gets null direction";

    // Try to leave current room.
    Room nextRoom = currentRoom.getExit(direction);
    if (nextRoom == null) {
        return "There is no exit in that direction!";
    } else {
        currentRoom = nextRoom;
        return currentRoom.getLongDescription();
    }
}
```

To go into a specific room to end the game i.e "throne" room here's what I did :

```
    if (currentRoom.equals(throne)) {
        finished = true;
        return "Congrats you have reached the throne room";
    }
```

But I keep getting this error : `cannot find symbol - variable throne`

This is a project based on the "Object first with Java using blueJ"

Comment: pass the variable as parameter in second method. or make it instance or class variable

Comment: You've declared `throne` as a local variable inside a method. You either have to pass the variable as a parameter to the enclosing method that your last segment is based on or make the `throne` variable a class member.

Comment: i don't think you are calling goRoom() from createRoom() so make it instance variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of declaring the Room throne in your `private void createRooms()`, you can declare it as a field, so right after the constructor you can say `Room throne;`, you can then still initialize it in your `createRooms` method.

You could consider making it `final` because it won't change anymore and that clearly states the intention

In this case I wouldn't pass it to the next parameter, to me it would make sense to have it as a field

Edit: on the topic of your unreachable statement comment, what I suspect you're doing is checking for the finished state of the game after your following code:

```
} else {
        currentRoom = nextRoom;
        return currentRoom.getLongDescription();
    }
```

Because you're already returning from the method here, you're never actually checking for the end state of the game.

Comment: I declared the Room throne as "private Room throne;" in the field area, I am getting this error and used if (currentRoom.equals(throne))
        {
            finished = true;
            return "Congrats you have reached the throne room";
        } but i'm getting this error "unreachable statement"

Comment: Can you update your post with the full new code? And on what line are you getting this exactly?

Comment: Also in your updated code you named the throne room 'Goal'? I would use lowercase for the naming there

Comment: I updated my post with what I think is causing your unreachable statement error.

Comment: Updated. I am getting this error on this line "if (currentRoom.equals(throne))..". Also, what did you mean by "making it final"

Comment: See my latest edit, I'm pretty sure that's what's causing your unreachable statement error. I can't know for sure unless you post the full method this is happening in though.
On final: you could say private final Room throne;, then you are sure it must have been assigned and also sure that you can't accidentally change the value later

Comment: Would be nice if you could let us know if that was indeed the problem and if you can mark the answer as accepted if it is :)

Comment: I also needed to remove the variable "Room throne;" from the "createRooms" method.

Comment: Yes indeed, otherwise you'd still refer to that one inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing your `Room`s as *local* variables. These variables are deleted as soon as your method terminates, so the `Room`s will disappear.

To solve this, you should declare your variables at the class level:

```
public class Game {
    private Room currentRoom;
    private boolean finished;
    private Room Goal;
    private Map<String, Room> rooms;


public Game() {
    finished = false;
    rooms = new HashMap<>();
    createRooms();
}

//....

private void createRooms() {
    rooms.put("gate", new Room("outside the old gate at the castle"));
    //similar for other rooms
    //...
}
```

Then, you can access your rooms by defining a function

```
public Room getRoom(String roomName) {
    if (rooms.containsKey(roomName))
        return rooms.get(roomName);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such room: " + roomName);
}
```

For example:

```
if (currentRoom.equals(getRoom("throne")) {

        finished = true;
        return "Congrats you have reached the throne room";
}
```

If `goRoom()` is not in `Game`, you will need to get an instance of `Game` first, and then call `getRoom()` on that instance.

Comment: how can I implement this without adding further method "getRoom". I want to be able to use the "goRoom" method only. Thanks

Comment: Provided that `goRoom()` is located in `Game`, you could also use `rooms.get("throne")`

Answer (score 1):

> But I keep getting this error : "cannot find symbol - variable
>   throne". I believe i need a field somewhere but I am unsure where and
>   how this is useful.

You are getting this error because variable `throne` is a local variable whose scope is just inside the method it is declared

```
private void createRooms()
{
    Room gate, graveyard, church, crypt, entrance, hall, kitchen, buttery, greathall, staircase,
        dungeon, topstaircase, throne, solar, wardrobe, privy;


    // create the rooms
    gate = new Room("outside the old gate of the castle");
    graveyard = new Room("on a wind-swept gaveyard");
    church = new Room("in a small ancient church");
    throne = new Room("in the throne room with golden walls");// local variable
    // other rooms ...

    // initialise room exits

    gate.setExit("north", graveyard);
    throne.setExit("south", topstaircase);
    // other exits ...
    }
```

Now Instead of making it local you can make it as `instance variable` or `class variable` so it can be  accessible , if you wish to make this variable as `private instance variable` then provide getters and setters to access this variable's value .